# Pandas Keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple code:

```
stats2 = {'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'b':[43,34,65,56,29,76],
         'c':[65,67,78,65,45,52],
         'cac':['mns','ab','cd','cd','ab','k']}
f2 = pd.DataFrame(stats2)
f2.set_index(['cac'], inplace = True)
print(f2.ix['mns'])
print(f2['mns'])
```

f2.ix['mns'] works just fine. However, f2['mns'] reports KeyError. I am trying to understand why it does that. Is that how pandas work? Do I have to use ix even though I have set the index before?

Comment: `f2['mns']` is looking for a column named `mns`.  To access the row with that index, you can either use `f2.ix['mns']` or `f2.loc['mns']`. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data

Comment: So what is the point of setting index? I thought i could use index to access the row in a data frame. I was able to use the index like that in below example: `f2['st']= pd.to_datetime(f2['st'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
 
  f2.set_index(['st'], inplace = True)
 
  print(f2['2016-02-08 22:46'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your original dataframe:

```
>>> df

   a   b   c  cac
0  1  43  65  mns
1  2  34  67   ab
2  3  65  78   cd
3  4  56  65   cd
4  5  29  45   ab
5  6  76  52    k


>>> df.set_index(['cac'], inplace=True)
>>> df

     a   b   c
cac           
mns  1  43  65
ab   2  34  67
cd   3  65  78
cd   4  56  65
ab   5  29  45
k    6  76  52
```

So, setting the index in pandas is simply replacing the before counter values(0,1,2,...,5) to the new row values i.e (mns, ab,...,k) of `cac` column name.

```
>>> df.ix['mns']

a     1
b    43
c    65
```

This command specifically searches for row in the index column, `cac` whose value is equal to `mns` and retrieves it's corresponding elements.

***Note:***  As `mns` is not a column name of the dataframe, `df['mns']` throws a key error.